# Exclude Service with spaces in name in NRPE arguments

Tags: service, nrpe, icinga, icinga2, sophos

exclude=edgeupdate    =   working fine

exclude=Sophos Clean Service      = not working

what syntax do I have to use here?

Answer (score 0):

```
'exclude=Sophos Clean Service'
```

But you might be using the `Display name`. Make sure you use the real `Service name`

A good example for this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The display name is Sophos Clean, the Service name: Sophos Clean Service WITH Spaces :-( if I add the nrpe argument: exclude=Sophos Clean Service it translates the command I can inspect to 'exclude=Sophos Clean Service' Plugin = CHECK_NRPE: Invalid packet type received from server.